# How to create car collision in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a background with a top view motorway and forest on the sides and I want it so that when the car touches the green forest area the game changes to another scene. I have tried to put a line on the forest area and make it so that if the car hits the line switch to another scene but I have failed. I'm using action scrip 3. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be to put the track pavement graphic in a separate sprite that sits on top of the green forest. Then you can [hit test](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject()) to see when your car is not touching the road. That would mean it's in the forest.

There's a simple top-down racing game in this book that uses a similar technique: [AS3 Game Programming University](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0789747324) ([site](http://flashgameu.com))

Taking a look at that book might be really helpful if you are just starting out with games.

Comment: I have separated the forest and road into two different sprites and I have added the following code and the collision still doesn't work.         if (blueCar4.hitTestObject(ForestCollision1_mc)) 
 {
  gotoAndPlay(1, "Game Over");
  blueCar4.visible=false;
 }
else
 
 {
  gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene Forest");
 }                                                                                                   //blueCar4 is the car and ForestCollision1_mc is the collision object. How can I make it work? Thanks for the help